# I got the error like Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, magento, select, join

My query is like ..

```
SELECT  oi.`sku`,oi.`product_id`, count(*) as `count1`
                FROM `order_item` AS oi RIGHT JOIN `products` AS p ON oi.`product_id` =  p.`entity_id` WHERE oi.`product_id` IN (1234,4556,7854)
                GROUP BY oi.`sku` ORDER BY `count1` DESC
```

i got the error like below..

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') 
>   GROUP BY sfoi.`sku` ORDER BY `count1` DESC' at line 4'

Please can you guys explain this ,is there any wrong on my query?

Comment: no space at all...actually those values are passed like dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You should GROUP BY  by two columns: oi.sku,oi.product_id

```
SELECT oi.sku,oi.product_id, count(*) as count1 
FROM order_item AS oi 
RIGHT JOIN products AS p ON oi.product_id = p.entity_id 
WHERE oi.product_id IN (1234,4556,7854) 
GROUP BY oi.sku,oi.product_id
ORDER BY count1 DESC
```